# ASP.NET Self Update System

Tags: asp.net, auto-update

The customer requires us to install our asp.net-based web system on their intranet server. As soon as the initial adjustments are done, the server will be made completely inaccessible to us (due to security reasons as you might have guessed). On the other hand, we are still responsible for maintenance and ongoing development.

So I am after some kind of auto update system. It is deemed like a windows service working side by side with the site and periodically polling central server for updates. Assuming the central server is under developers' control, such approach would solve the problem.

The question is whether such systems exist, either commercial or free/open source. Have anybody heard of them? We are a bit limited in time and would prefer to accommodate ready made solution rather than writing it from scratch.

Comment: wxBuild/wxUpdate is popular, but I don't know if it supports an update service.

Comment: I find the security gain a bit dubious though. Since you still can deploy arbitrary binaries to their server which are then executed.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I work at a bank, where limited to no access is common for vendors.  Obviously the OP's client trusts them not to deliver malware.  If the client is risk-averse, they may have legitimate reasons to restrict access to their infrastructure.

Comment: Did you come up with a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phil Haack has a library that he's putting together to enable this, although I agree with Dave's answer that you should not be responsible for it if you can't be in control of it.

See [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/15/building-a-self-updating-site-using-nuget.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am not familiar with nuget at all, does it support database schema updates? Is it capable to preserve instance-specific files? Different instances of the site will have their own sets of files related to look and layout (images and css files). It is necessary to keep them regardless of what the update contains.

Comment: Phil never finished his library from what I can tell. Looked promising.

Comment: Nuget is a system for pulling external libraries, such as Ninject or ELMAH, into your project.  It integrates with Visual Studio.  It is released, but it wouldn't address the OP's problem.

Comment: Nuget itself would not solve the problem, but the library that Phil was working on would have gone at least part way there

Answer (score 3):

If you won't have any access to this system, I don't think an auto-update service would be a good idea.  Your client is effectively taking partial responsibility for supporting your application by locking you out.  This is common but should be mutually understood.

Updates should be applied as separate installation packages with rollback capability.  If you don't have access to the server, the client takes on responsibility for applying updates.  If your client is uncomfortable with that arrangement, you should discuss "guided" access where you are able to access the server under the supervision of your client's IT staff.